# Grouping in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grouping

I have a code in a view:

```
<% @insurer.offices.includes(:city).order('cities.name asc').each do |office| %>
    <div class="headline">
      <h4><%= office.city.name %></h4>
    </div>
    <p><%= office.name %></p>
  <% end %>
```

After this loop I can see the cities and offices in these cities, but the cities are repeated like:

```
New York:
Office address

New York:
Other office address
```

I need to show all offices grouped by a city. I tried to 
`<% @insurer.offices.includes(:city).group('cities.name').order('cities.name asc').each do |office| %>`, but it doesn't work.
Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this and it helped:

```
<% @all_insurers.each do |city, office| %>
  <div class="headline">
    <h4><%= city.name %></h4>
  </div>
  <% office.each do |city_office| %>
    <%= city_office.name%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my insurers_controller:

```
def show
  @insurer = Insurer.find(params[:id])
  @all_insurers = @insurer.offices.includes(:city).order('cities.name asc').group_by(&:city)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is designed to give you one office at a time. Even if cities are grouped, when you have 3 new york offices, it will run the loop 3 times.

To group offices under a common city headline, you need to group office by city, and your loop need to remember the previous city, and display the headline only when the city changes.

Add a variable like `previous_city` (it probably need to be initialized before the loop with nil), and display the headline only if `previous_city == office.city` and at the end of the loop you can do `previous_city = office.city`

Another thing, `@insurer.offices.includes(:city).order('cities.name asc')` should be in a variable defined in the controller.